# Angular http called once and available in all controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I need to call http service once before all templates are loaded ( using ui-routing), and returned data available in all controllers, is that possible?

```
$http.get('localhost;8080/some.json').then(function(d) {
  return d;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run it once and make it available to all controllers, then create a service, say, `CoreData`, and call it from `app.run()` as follows

```
app.factory('CoreData',function($http) {
  var data, defer;
  return {
    load: function() {
      defer = $http.get('localhost;8080/some.json');
    },
    get: function() {
        return defer;
    }
  };
})
.controller('CtrlA',function(CoreData) {
   $scope.foo = CoreData.get();
})
.controller('CtrlB',function(CoreData) {
   $scope.foo = CoreData.get();
})
.run(function(CoreData) {
   CoreData.load();
});
```

If you are concerned about timing, you can do the above `.get()` as a promise with a single method on `CoreData`.

To handle the loading, we just pass the `$http` promise back, which is automatically populated by angular when resolved.

Comment: Just one question: it doesn't work with index.html MainController, it is undefined there.. Is it possible to make it available in that controller for index.html?

Comment: I didn't understand that follow on?

Comment: I have index.html which has div with ng-view directive for routing. I have header and menu HTML defined in that index.html and I defined main controller for that index.html. I need that json data available in index.html also, because header and menu items are showing from that json also. Do you understand better now?

Comment: Is it a timing issue? You could modify all of the above to use promises.

Comment: I don't know if it's timing. Index.html uses MainController where I call CoreData.get() but it returns undefined. All other controllers which use templates works like a charm.

Comment: You getting via `$http` from the server, so it needs to be a promise.

Comment: How to write a promise?

Comment: I will edit above. Nice little trick that all $scope properties that are promises are automatically updated by angular when they are resolved.

Comment: Hm, this isn't working when I put that , HTML loads before anything

Comment: @firstChild, it should load, and then adjust afterwards. Are you not seeing that? You can eliminate the flicker with `ng-cloak`